# Making a window close by a specific value (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a window close out after a button is clicked a certain amount of times and one of the two radio buttons are selected. Currently this is my code (at least the bit that applies):

```
from tkinter import *
slide=1
window2=Tk()

window2.title("Select Game Length")
window2.geometry('1600x800+0+0')

def next_slide_window2():
    global slide
    slide += 1
    if slide==1:
        window2_bg.config(image=intro1)
    elif slide==2:
        window2_bg.config(image=intro2)
    elif slide==3:
        window2_bg.config(image=intro3)
        game_length_select_btn1.place(x=390, y=350)
        game_length_select_btn2.place(x=790, y=350)
    elif slide>=4 and game_length.get != 0:
        window2.destroy()

best_of_3 = PhotoImage(file="bestof3.png")
best_of_5 = PhotoImage(file="bestof5.png")
intro1 = PhotoImage(file="window2_intro1.png")
intro2 = PhotoImage(file="window2_intro2.png")
intro3 = PhotoImage(file="window2_intro3.png")
next = PhotoImage(file="next.png")

window2_bg=Label(window2,image=intro1)
window2_bg.place(y=50, x=500) #at school, 50, 690; at home, 50, 500

next_button=Button(window2, image=next, command=next_slide_window2)
next_button.place(y=650, x=700) #at school, 800, 900; at home 650, 700

game_length=IntVar()
game_length.set(0)

game_length_select_btn1= Radiobutton(window2, image=best_of_3, 
variable=game_length, value=3, command=game_length_select)

game_length_select_btn2= Radiobutton(window2, image=best_of_5, 
variable=game_length, value=5, command=game_length_select)

window2.mainloop()
```

After the next button is pressed for the fourth time, it destroys the window whether or not one of the radio buttons is selected. This should only be happening if one of them are. What's wrong?

Comment: Should `game_length.get` be `game_length.get()` inside `next_slide_window2()`?

Comment: @acw1668 wow yeah that was way too simple. Sorry. Can you go ahead and answer that so I can mark it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the variable's `get` function reference `game_length.get` in comparison inside `next_slide_window2()` function.

Change `game_length.get` to `game_length.get()` so that you are using the value of `game_length` variable.